# Allow breaking long words in table cell automatically

Tags: tabularx

Is it possible to break long **words** (note, not lines) in table cell without adding `\-` or `\allowbreak`?

Current code is:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{3.5cm}|p{3.5cm}|X|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
Name & Name & Name & Name & Name & Name \\
\hline
 & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

How to allow long word breaking in, for example, first cell? In case, when word does **not** have white spaces? Position of line break is not important, let text just fill the cell and break if necessary.

Comment: You can add `>{\raggedright}p{3.5cm}` so that line breaking in narrow columns is more reasonable, but it will break at white space, not add additional hyphenation points to words

Comment: yeah David, i need a solution to break when there are no white-spaces. I will edit question to bold it.

Comment: You are making TeX do a lot of work to find the width of that middle column using tabularx, you could just use `tabular` and tell it the answer `p{\dimexpr\textwidth-17cm-7\arrayrulewidth-12\tabcolsep}` (how big is your paper, that's negative in most classes:-)

Comment: There are answers to show how to break strings at an arbitrary character I'll see if I can spot the duplicate question

Comment: See for example this for breaking at CamelCase, it could be adapted to allow breaking at other, or every, letter http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66593/automatic-camel-case-breaking/66603#66603

Comment: see also [Lines too long due to text inside custom command not being hyphenated](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29095/579) regarding the fact that tex will never hyphenate the first word in a table cell.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late for this particular question, but I had the exactly same necessity as the op and found a way to solve it. I share the solution so that it can be helpful for other people having the same problem.

Very simply, the [seqsplit package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/seqsplit) offers the `\seqsplit{}` command, that allows for breaking of long words at any position where Tex would like to (e.g. at the end of a table).